# Making simple table in MATLAB GUI, like Excel

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I just want to make a simple table like Excel in MATLAB GUI. Please see attached fig:

[image]

Column 'unit' and 'value' are editable. Column 'sum' should be unit*value.

Questions:
How can I add header parameters?

How can I change property of column 'sum'= unit*value?

How can I change property of column 'Result'=sum ' sum' column / EDOC?

I just made demo input.

```
    % Code% sim.m

    function varargout = Sim(varargin)
    % SIM MATLAB code for Sim.fig
    %      SIM, by itself, creates a new SIM or raises the existing
    %      singleton*.
    %
    %      H = SIM returns the handle to a new SIM or the handle to
    %      the existing singleton*.
    %
    %      SIM('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the local
    %      function named CALLBACK in SIM.M with the given input arguments.
    %
    %      SIM('Property','Value',...) creates a new SIM or raises the
    %      existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value pairs are
    %      applied to the GUI before Sim_OpeningFcn gets called.  An
    %      unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application
    %      stop.  All inputs are passed to Sim_OpeningFcn via varargin.
    %
    %      *See GUI Options on GUIDE's Tools menu.  Choose "GUI allows only one
    %      instance to run (singleton)".
    %
    % See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES

    % Edit the above text to modify the response to help Sim

    % Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 25-Dec-2014 15:33:04

    % Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
    gui_Singleton = 1;
    gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                       'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                       'gui_OpeningFcn', @Sim_OpeningFcn, ...
                       'gui_OutputFcn',  @Sim_OutputFcn, ...
                       'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                       'gui_Callback',   []);
    if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
        gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
    end

    if nargout
        [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
    else
        gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
    end
    % End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


    % --- Executes just before Sim is made visible.
    function Sim_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
    % This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
    % hObject    handle to figure
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
    % varargin   command line arguments to Sim (see VARARGIN)

    % Choose default command line output for Sim
    handles.output = hObject;

    % Update handles structure
    guidata(hObject, handles);

    % UIWAIT makes Sim wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
    % uiwait(handles.figure1);


    % --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
    function varargout = Sim_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
    % varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
    % hObject    handle to figure
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

    % Get default command line output from handles structure
    varargout{1} = handles.output;


    % --- Executes during object deletion, before destroying properties.
    function Costfunction_DeleteFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % hObject    handle to Costfunction (see GCBO)
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)


    % --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
    function Costfunction_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    % hObject    handle to Costfunction (see GCBO)
    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
    % handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A matlab component called [uitable](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uitable.html) will be your GUI object.
Editing the value interactively could be done in different ways, [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/synchronized-data-presentations-in-a-programmatic-gui.html) has a complete example.